# rails3-jquery-autocomplete: show image in results list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem found [here.](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) I'm querying a table of users and would like the drop down to show the user's profile image next to the name. I have a `User` model and a polymorphic `Image` model. Each User `:has_one` image. In the image model, I'm using the paperclip to attach images, referred to in the model as a `pic`.

The `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem, in the documentation, says I can specify a `:display_value` in the controller. I'm using this technique and it works fine; that is to say, I had a custom method for returning a value and it is returned properly. That custom method is in the User model, per the proper setup of the gem. What I would like to do is to return the `:tiny` version of the user's image and display it to the left of the name in the drop down list. The following display method works fine:

```
def autocomplete_list_display
    "#{full_name}"
end
```

I tried to do the following:

```
def autocomplete_list_display
    i = self.image
    "#{image_tag(i.pic(:tiny))}" + " #{full_name}"
end
```

I get the error that

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'image_tag' for #<User id: 4, full_name: "My Name">):
```

If I leave out the `image_tag()` part, then the URL of the image displays properly. I cannot seem to get this to appear as rendered HTML, however, even using the `.html_safe` method on it. Note, I also tried the following, but it did not render as HTML:

```
def autocomplete_list_display
    i = self.image
    "<img src='#{i.pic(:tiny)}' />"
end
```

How do I write a `:display_value...` method that will allow me to embed HTML in the results and show the user image next to the name? Can this be done via the method, or does it have to be done in javascript? (In the latter case, how do I modify the .js file to show the image?)

Answer (score 2):

The HTML gets escaped by jQuery. According to [the jQuery Autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), you can use [Scott González' html extension](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js) to prevent that from happening.

If you include that extension in your project, you can set the autocomplete html option to true for your autocomplete field:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ html: true });
```

Then, whatever your display_value function returns will be rendered as HTML.